# How is "fraction" linear equation solved? Help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\dfrac{x+5}{2}=25$$

I need help solving a problem that has an equation on the top and a number at the bottom. I don't understand what to do with the "$2$".

Comment: Try multiplying both sides by $2$, and use the fact that $$2 \cdot \frac{x + 5}{2} = \left(\frac 2 2 \right) (x + 5)$$

Comment: If you think of it as 
$$
\frac{x+5}{2} = \frac{25}{1}
$$
You can solve this by "cross-multiplying" first

Comment: Just to correct your wording: The item on top of the horizontal bar is not an equation, but rather an expression. The entire thing is an equation: It has an equal sign asserting that “something” is equal to “something else;” and that fact is what makes the entire thing an equation.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides of the equation by $2$. You then have $x+5=50$. Can you proceed from there?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides of the equation by $2$. This is allowed because it is an equation.
$2 \times \frac{x+5}{2} = 25 \times 2$

$x+5 = 50$

Can you solve from here?

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{x+5}{2}=25$

Cross multiply the $2$

$[(2)]\dfrac{x+5}{2}=25 (2)$

The 2 on the left cancels since there is a 2 in the numerator and 2 in the denominator

$x+5=(25)(2)$

$x+ 5 = 50$

Subtract 5 on both sides

$x = 45$

Plugging $45$ back into the equation. We have

$45+5=50$

$50=50$

We can also plug $45$ back into the original equation

$\dfrac{45+5}{2}=25$

$\dfrac{50}{2}=25$

$25=25$

Therefore, the answer is $ x = 45$

Answer (score 0):

Just read the equation out loud: “What number am I?  If you take the half of $5$ more than  I am you'll get $25$.”  Now think.